# How to import org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch in my Eclipse Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, apache-commons

How to use `StopWatch` from apache commons?
What do I download/install to use this class in my project?

Comment: you can download and add it into your project's classpath

Comment: Well, consider if everybody will ask question, how he could install particular library - what this  will be like?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no build system such as Ant, Maven e.t.c. In Eclipse you should use: *Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar -> Choose Downloaded [Apache Common Jar](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)*. This option will add your jar to the project's classpath. It means Java compiler and JVM know where find classes when you reference this class in your code. It will not additional cost in runtime if you have giant jar file because will load only those classes need to executing code(all you refer from your code and referred by library code).

Also, you may download sources file to attach for jar in IDE. After you are able to look library source code and javadoc in your IDE.

Also, you may consider [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) stopwatch implementation if you already have this one in your classpath.

Comment: I found this .jar file: commons-lang3-3.1.jar. I should import that? I only need one class and I see there are lots of stuff in there I won't use. Also there is another .jar file: commons-lang3-3.1-sources.jar. So, should I import the .jar with the binaries or the source files? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You should add to classpath only commons-land-3.3.1.jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Downoad the jar which contains the class you want to use.
In eclipse, right click on your project and select properties-java build path-libraries tab.
From there add your downloaded jar file.

Comment: Check out the comment I added at Taky's post below please :)